# Is there a way to "auto detect" the encoding of a resource when loading it using stringFromContentsOfURL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsstringencoding

Is there a way to "auto detect" the encoding of a resource when loading it using stringFromContentsOfURL? The current (non-depracated) method, `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error;`, wants a URL encoding. I've noticed that getting it wrong does make a difference for what I want to do. Is there a way to check this somehow and always get it right? (Right now I'm using UTF8.)

Comment: You may want to download the string yourself and check for the charset header.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try this function from the docs

Returns a string created by reading data from a given URL and returns by reference the encoding used to interpret the data.

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

this seems to guess the encoding and then returns it to you

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do when converting data (encoding-less string of bytes) to a string is attempt to initialize the string using various different encodings.  I would suggest trying the most limiting (charset wise) encodings like ASCII and UTF-8 first, then attempt UTF-16.  If none of those are a valid encoding, you should attempt to decode the string using a fallback encoding like `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` that will almost always work.  In order to do this you need to download the page's contents using NSData so that you don't have to re-download for every encoding attempt.  Your code might look like this:

```
NSData * urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL];
NSString * theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if (!theString) {
    theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
if (!theString) {
    theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
}
if (!theString) {
    theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
}
// ...
// use theString here...
// ...
[theString release];
```

Comment: And will `theString` always be nil if it's not initialized with the right encoding?