# conversion from UInt8 to String in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am converting following UInt8 array to String in swift and getting nil          each time.what i should do ?? please help me.

```
[ 201, 201, 87, 200, 204 ]
let decData = NSData(bytes: mydata, length: Int(mydata.count) )
let result1 = NSString(data: decData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Edited :
I am using InflateStream/deflateStream to compress my data. The return type of deflateStream is UInt8. I tried to convert this value to string so that i can send it to server.

This is my code

```
    let string = "hello"
    let data: [UInt8] = Array(string.utf8)

    // compress
    var deflater = DeflateStream()
    var (deflated, err) = deflater.write(data, flush: true)
    if err != nil{
        fatalError("\(err!)")
    }
    print(" ***** deflater: \(deflated)")

    // decompress
    var inflater = InflateStream()
    var (inflated, errr) = inflater.write(deflated, flush: true)
    if errr != nil{
        fatalError("\(errr!)")
    }
    print(" ***** inflated: \(inflated)")
```

Comment: The array represents characters?  What output do you *expect* for `result1`? `"ÉÉWÈÌ"`?

Comment: may be I'm not sure because this array i m getting after compression.any ways how you got this can you please show me ?

Comment: The code is in my answer below.  Per an ASCII chart I just looked at, that's the correct string given the presumably ASCII values you provided.

Comment: What does the data represent? It is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Perhaps some ISO-8859 encoding? Unicode code points? ... ? Without that information (or knowing the expected result) we can only *guess*.

Comment: @NomanAkhtar: Where does DeflateStream come from? I tried it with https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift (which has to be updated for Swift 2).   Then with your updated example, `inflated` becomes `[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]` and that *is* a valid UTF-8 sequence, and can be converted to the string "Hello" as in your first code snippet. Please post a (minimal) example demonstrating the *problem*.

Comment: Yes brother I got deflatorStream/inflatorStream from https://github.com/tidwall/DeflateSwift .but after deflating "hello" I m getting array of UInt8.when I m inflating it I m again getting the same "hello" .but the problem is that after deflating I have to convert the result into string so that I can send it to server.the I have already written logic to handle string I don't want to modify code  at server

Comment: You cannot interpret arbitrary binary data as a UTF-8 string. What format/encoding does the server expect? Perhaps you want to use Base64?

Comment: @Martin R: No brother, I am wanting iso-8859-1 format at server side .how can I get?

Comment: Then this might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34497065/1187415

Comment: Could you resolve the problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 6):

Given an array of `UInt8`:

```
let letters: [UInt8] = [201, 201, 87, 200, 204]
```

We can start by mapping this into an array of `Character`:

```
let characters = letters.map { Character(UnicodeScalar($0)) }
```

And then we just call the `String` constructor that expects `[Character]`:

```
let result = String(Array(characters))
```

Comment: here when i m again getting UInt8 using following code the output is comming different     [ let data: [UInt8] = Array(result.utf8)   print(data)]

Comment: @NomanAkhtar: Of course, because `201, 201, 87, 200, 204` is *not* a valid UTF-8 sequence. Please let us know where the data comes from, what it represents, and what result you expect.

Comment: i m using deflator/inflater to compress data after compression i got this data i have to send this data in the form of string

Comment: let string = "hello"
        let data: [UInt8] = Array(string.utf8)
        
        // compress
        var deflater = DeflateStream()
        var (deflated, err) = deflater.write(data, flush: true)
        if err != nil{
            fatalError("\(err!)")
        }
        print(" ***** deflater: \(deflated)")
        
        // decompress
        var inflater = InflateStream()
        var (inflated, errr) = inflater.write(deflated, flush: true)
        if errr != nil{
            fatalError("\(errr!)")
        }
        print(" ***** inflated: \(inflated)")

Comment: @NomanAkhtar Please add all relevant information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: This is a quite hypothetical solution, and also not applicable: mapping an unsigned eight bit integer to an Unicode Scalar should be a valid unicode value that can be represented as a single UInt8. The _given_ values - except `87` - are certainly not valid UTF-8 start bytes.