# can't get web page source from url in Swift

Tags: swift, http

I'm currently using SwiftHTTP for getting source of url address. I am using 'get method' for getting source code of url address which is

```
 do {
            let opt = try HTTP.GET(self.my_url_address!)
            opt.start { response in
                if let err = response.error {
                    print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                    return 
                }
                print(response.description)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
        }
```

after this code run I got this output in Xcode output screen

```
URL: http://myweburl.com/detay/swat-under-siege.html

Status Code: 200

Headers: Content-Type: text/html 
Connection: keep-alive 
CF-RAY: 38391215a60e2726-FRA 
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSABBBSDT=HPKKPJGCDLKMDMILNGHPCAGD; path=/ 
Date: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 18:51:24 GMT 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Transfer-Encoding: Identity 
Server: cloudflare-nginx 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Cache-Control: private
```

The status code is 200 but the output is not the source code of url. How can I fix this?

Comment: The documentation mentions `print("data is: \(response.data)")`.

Comment: the output is : "data is: 27905 bytes". I try let responseString = String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8); which is doesn't work the output is only  "nil"

Comment: Try using a plain old URLSession and check if the problem persists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is correct. I've tried requesting the website (the real one) and it works:

```
print(response.data.base64EncodedString())
```

If you decode the BASE64 data, it will render valid HTML code.

The issue seems related to encoding. After checking the website's head tag, it states that the charset is `windows-1254`

```
String(data: response.data, encoding: .windowsCP1254) // works. latin1, etc.
```

Your issue is similar to [SWIFT: NSURLSession convert data to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32695683/2124535)

Comment: String(data: response.data, encoding: .windowsCP1254) is the answer!. Thank you very much!